# Find the range of convergence of the series$\,\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

The series I have is
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\dfrac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}}$$

The same series with absolute values is:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\dfrac{|z|^n}{1+|z|^{2n}}}$$

Using D'Alembert's principle,
$$\displaystyle\lim {\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}} = {\dfrac{|z|^n \cdot |z|}{1+|z|^{2n} \cdot |z|}} \cdot {\dfrac{1+|z|^{2n}}{|z|^n}} = |z|$$

The convergence range is when $|z| < 1$. But the book answer is $|z| \ne 1$.

Comment: What's $Z_n$? Is it actually $Z^n$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Updated

Comment: I don't think the calculation of $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n$ is correct.

Comment: So what is wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't $|z|>1$ and $|z|<1$ lead to different results?

Comment: Okay, I see what's wrong. It should be $2(n+1)$, not $2n+1$, therefore
$$\lim {\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}} = {\frac{|Z|^n \cdot |Z|^2}{1+|Z|^{2n} \cdot |Z|^2}} \cdot {\frac{1+|Z|^{2n}}{|Z|^n}} = 1$$. But this time I have the limit one....

Comment: @user3132457: $ \displaystyle\lim {\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}} = {\dfrac{|z|^n\ \cdot |z|}{1+|z|^{2n} \cdot |z|^2}} \cdot {\dfrac{1+|z|^{2n}}{|z|^n}} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|z|=r<1$, and $n\ge 1$, then 
$$
\left|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\right|\le \frac{|z|^n}{1-|z|^{2n}}=\frac{r^n}{1-r^{2n}}
<\frac{r^n}{1-r}
$$
and hence the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}
$$
converges, due to Comparison Test.

If $|z|=1$, and in particular $z=i$, then the series is not even definable.

**Note.** This is not a power series, and hence finding the *radius of convergence* is out of question. Clearly, there exist values of $z$, with $|z|>1$, for which the series converges absolutely, i.e., all $z\in\mathbb R$, with $|z|>1$. Meanwhile, the unit circle is a natural boundary of the series, since, for the points $z=\exp(ik/2^\ell)$ are singularities (not isolated) of the series, for all $k,\ell\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: I don't get how $$\left|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\right|\le \frac{|z|^n}{1-|z|^{2n}}$$? If $z^{2n}$ is greater than 1, then the inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: This is true when $|z|=r<1$, as mentioned in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I know, but the answer is $|z| \ne 1$ which means $|z| > 1$ is possible to have.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac{1/z^n}{1+1/z^{2n}}\\
=\frac{z^n}{z^{2n}+1}\\
=a_n(z)$$
So it converges for $z$ whenever it converges for $1/z$.